# Using separate .nibs and getting logic out of App Delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a document based app using the standard template. I have two auxiliary panels in Main Menu.xib, and my main logic is currently in the App Delegate, mainly through an IBAction in App Delegate triggered by a button on one of my panels. Everything works fine, but I know it should be organised better.

I have implemented a Preferences panel as suggested by Hillegass in Chapter 12. So:

- Create a custom controller called AppController containing instance
  of PreferenceController. This is instantiated in Main Menu.xib
- Custom PreferenceController class which is subclass of 
  NSWindowController. This loads the Preferences.xib
- Preferences panel created in Preferences.xib

Before I get too far in the app’s development, I want to be sure I’m organising things the right way.

I want to move my main logic out of App Delegate, possibly into App Controller. I want App Controller to be in charge of showing and hiding the various panels, and I want each panel to have its own .xib.

I have created two more subclasses of NSWindowController and made them ivars of the AppController, alongside the PreferencesController eg. Panel1Controller & Panel2Controller.

My problem is that interface builder is not letting me connect an IBAction in AppController to a button on one of my panels. It only lets me connect to the .xib file’s owner, i.e. Panel1Controller in the case of Panel1.xib.

If I put the logic in Panel1Controller, how do I get at one of the other panels (say Panel2Controller?) in order to hide it?

Am I going about  this the right way?

Getting very confused….

Any help much appreciated!

Regards,

John

Comment: To be able to wire things up from Interface Builder you will need a reference to the target object inside Interface Builder. To do that, drag an "Object" from the Object Library into your App Controller's xib file. Then set the class of that object to your "AppController" class. One thing to remember when doing this, is that when you load the xib, the object will be instantiated automatically.

Finally, all of the Panel1Controller logic should be in the Panel1Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just for simplicity sake I'd move all the nib elements controlled by the NSWindowController sub-classes out of the main nib and into nibs with the same name as the (NSWindowController) sub-classes that control them. DON'T expose IBOutlets or IBActions in the sub-class headers (they should be in a class extension ("@interface MyWindowController ()") in the source file for that sub-class.
Also, is the AppController a 2nd app delegate? Probably not what you want (there can only be one); you should merge its logic into the existing app delegate if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the App Delegate separate from the AppController. I've read this is good practice. Each .xib has its own custom sub-class of NSWindowController, which is also the file's owner. Trouble is I cannot see how to say, press a button on one window to close another window. How do they communicate when one doesn't know about the other?

Comment: Talk to the common denominator: the application delegate ([NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate); it should know about all window controllers and it can tell them when to close.

Comment: I want to avoid using the App Delegate for anything other than implementing the NSApplicationDelgate protocol methods. I've tried loading .xibs from my AppController class and not using NSWindowController at all. This works, but the windows do not appear in the Window menu. There must be a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Just use the app delegate as the intermediary communication controller. IOW ask it to tell the other window controller to close its window.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [this](http://parmanoir.com/Bindings,_Outlets,_Target+Action_across_multiple_NIBs) method.

This seems to do away with **NSWindowController** altogether, and make the AppController the file's owner of both .xibs. This way IB allows you to create outlets in AppController for each window, and contain actions.

I have created a very simple, two-window app using this method that hides one window when a button on the other is pressed. Before I go away and re-organise my main app, I want to be sure I'm doing this the correct, standard way, if there is one?

[This](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html) page contradicts this method, by saying one window = one .xib + one NSWindowController subclass.

If you do it the latter way, how can one window talk to another, when you can't create outlets/actions in the AppController? Actions implemented in a window's NSWindowController class can't see outlets of another window, so how can they communicate?

This seems like pretty standard, basic stuff and yet I cannot find any sources which say which way is correct/best practice.

Comment: That's ok for simple applications but once you get more complex (like multiple windows with different table views) you'll have to write a lot more code to determine which control is calling a given delegate method, etc. You're better off then going with one window controller per window. You may always add more methods to your app controller/delegate. -(IBAction)closeTheOtherWindows:(id)sender;

Comment: Thanks, I get this. But, how can closeTheOtherWindows be connected as an outlet? Interface Builder only lets you connect outlets to the .xib file's owner, which will be the NSWindowController subclass for each window. If outlets and actions for each window are encapsulated within their respective NSWindowControllers, how can they talk to each other?

Comment: Yeah, don't do it as an IBAction (my bad); just do it as a (non-IBAction) method. Define it in the app controller(/delegate)'s header file which you'll #include in your window controller. Then an IBAction method there will call the (non-IBAction) method in the app controller(/delegate).

Comment: Aha... this is so simple yet obvious. I will give this a try later this week! Thanks.

Comment: Just tried this - but still have same problem - how do I access the instance of AppController from my NSWindowcontroller subclasses, in order to call one of its methods? Do I have to somehow make the AppController a delegate of the NSWindowController?

Comment: [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Comment: Thanks - but won't that return my App Delegate? I want to put the methods in my App Controller class! Sorry if this is obvious...

Comment: Yes… in that case you want a reference to the app controller… how to get this depends on how it was instantiated. If it was loaded via the main nib then you can bind it to an IBOutlet property of your app delegate and then use my code to get the delegate and then access the property.

Comment: If you sub-classed NSApplication then [NSApplication sharedApplication] should be your sub-class instance.

Comment: see: <http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/29280-how-to-get-the-application-object.html>

Comment: Thank you. Haven't had a chance to try this yet - will do tomorrow!

However, it does seem a rather roundabout way of doing things. Is there a more elegant way? Or a more accepted or standard way of achieving what I want? It seems like a pretty basic thing to do, yet I can't seem to find a general consensus on how to achieve it, keeping code elegant and still confirming to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I have read about [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1282595) mentions using Notifications.

I'm still wondering though - which is the most common "accepted" method of loading two or more windows in separate .nibs and getting them to talk to each other? I'm surprise this info has been so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to follow this pattern, separate AppDelegate and AppController, then your MainMenu.xib should not contain any window objects of any kind...it should just contain the application menu. Each additional window (NSWindow/NSPanel, etc.) gets its own .xib and its own NSWindowController.

There are two ways to assign references to your properties (IBOutlets) and methods (IBActions): 1) programatically, 2) via Interface Builder. Let's cover the second method!

To be able to wire things up from Interface Builder (IB) you will need a reference to the target object inside IB. For the MainMenu.xib file, this gets setup automatically: the MainMenu.xib contains an "AppDelegate" Object reference. The Object reference exposes the properties and methods in the AppDelegate class that are prefixed by the "IBAction" and "IBOutlet" macros. I write *Object* (with a capital *O*) because it is a widget available in the "Object Library" in IB.

You can easily create an instance of a custom objects inside a .xib file (via IB) by dragging an "Object" widget from the Object Library into your .xib. Then set the Object's class to that of your custom class. Once you've done this, the IBActions and IBOutlets in your custom class object will be available in IB. [Note: one thing to remember when doing this, is that when you load the xib, the object will be instantiated automatically. No need to alloc and init from within AppDelegate...you still have to call showWindow: on it].

As you mentioned, another approach is to simply have all of your additional .xib files owned by the AppController. That would be convenient, but it also gets 100% away from the architecture that you were trying to follow in the first place. In other words, if you're going to follow that style, why not just skip the separate AppDelegate and AppController in the first place, and just stick with the former (which would then be a Controller and Delegate).